# Calculate average from the 5 last dates in xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml that shows the date/time and a value volume in arguments. The xml looks like this:

```
<data volume="1" date="Tue, 04 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET"/>
<data volume="5" date="Wed, 05 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET"/>
<data volume="1" date="Thu, 06 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET"/>
<data volume="2" date="Fri, 07 Feb 2014 12:00 pm CET"/>
<data volume="3" date="Fri, 07 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET"/>
<data volume="4" date="Sat, 08 Feb 2014 12:00 am CET"/>
<data volume="4" date="Sat, 08 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET"/>
<data volume="1" date="Sun, 09 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET"/>
```

I want to calculate average volume from the last 5 days, that will be Feb 09 - Feb 05. How can I do it in C#? And another question how can I calculate average volume from day that has multiple times? Like

```
<data volume="2" date="Fri, 07 Feb 2014 12:00 pm CET"/>
<data volume="3" date="Fri, 07 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET"/>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
        XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc2.SelectNodes("data");

        foreach (XNode n in nodes)
        {   }
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: What I've done is take the attribute date of the last node and store it in a local variable. After that I don't know how to take the other dates

Comment: I use read the xml, select single node and take the date attribute             DateTime date;
            date = Convert.ToDateTime(Node1.Attributes["date"]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq to XML, below will give you some idea to start

```
var xelement = XElement.Parse(@"<root>
<data volume=""1"" date=""Tue, 04 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET""/>
<data volume=""5"" date=""Wed, 05 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET""/>
<data volume=""1"" date=""Thu, 06 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET""/>
<data volume=""2"" date=""Fri, 07 Feb 2014 12:00 pm CET""/>
<data volume=""3"" date=""Fri, 07 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET""/>
<data volume=""4"" date=""Sat, 08 Feb 2014 12:00 am CET""/>
<data volume=""4"" date=""Sat, 08 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET""/>
<data volume=""1"" date=""Sun, 09 Feb 2014 10:00 am CET""/>
</root>");

var fiveItems = xelement.Elements("data")
.Select(x=> new{Date = DateTime.Parse(x.Attribute("date").Value.TrimEnd("CET".ToCharArray()))
                 ,Volume = int.Parse(x.Attribute("volume").Value)})
.GroupBy(x=>x.Date.Date)
.Select(x=> new{ Date = x.Key, Volume = x.Average(k=>k.Volume)})
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date)
.Take(5);
```

if you loading from file

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var fiveItems = doc.Elements("data")
.Select(x=> new{Date = DateTime.Parse(x.Attribute("date").Value.TrimEnd("CET".ToCharArray()))
                 ,Volume = int.Parse(x.Attribute("volume").Value)})
.GroupBy(x=>x.Date.Date)
.Select(x=> new{ Date = x.Key, Volume = x.Average(k=>k.Volume)})
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date)
.Take(5);
```

above will calculate average for 5 days. if you want to calculate average for those five days again, do as below

```
TextBox1.Text = fiveItems.Average(x=>x.Volume);
```

Comment: i'm using the data from data.xml file

Comment: what I was thinking is, if there is more than one data from the same date, take the highest and the lowest volume, calculate average, so that average will be the value of the volume for that day

Comment: how can i also show the calculated average value in a textbox?

Comment: i'm sorry but the textbox is not taking the value from fiveItems.Averabe(x=>x.Volume);